# Map<String, String> as request parameter in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am migrating my spring boot application from 1.5.x to 2.3.x. After updating the required dependencies, in a controller having below method, getting one error:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<MyResult> getTestRes(
                                       @RequestParam("test1") final String test1,
                                       @RequestParam("test2") final String test2,
                                       @RequestParam("test3") final String test3,
                                       @RequestParam Map<String, String> reqParam,
                                       final HttpServeletRequest req) throws Exception {

        //method body.....
}
```

When i try to build the application, i get below error:

> [ERROR] Cant use non-primitive type: java.util.Map<java.lang.String,
> java.lang.String> as request parameter.

*I am using Spring boot 2.3.9.RELEASE version with Spring framework 5.2.13.RELEASE.*

Please let me know how can i resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: I think the error is clear: you can't use Map as a request parameter.

Comment: But it was working with old version and i dont see any changes regarding this kind of change in release notes. Please tell me what could be a possible fix for this error.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the error during the Maven/Gradle build? Created minimal viable app [here](https://codeshare.io/9OOPX4) to replicate the issue, but build passed and even getting the response. Used `spring-boot-starter-parent 2.3.9.RELEASE` only.

Comment: @sas...Yes, i am just trying mvn clean install. Thanks for your effort in replication. Actually same code was working with Spring boot 1.5.1.Release but i really have no idea why its not working with 2.3.9.Release.

Comment: You can have an object to [gather all your request parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67106703/2834978) but I'm not sure if mixing is allowed.

Comment: Has anyone heard about MultiValueMap, trying this...hope it will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using POST, I suggest you to do something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteData",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public Result getTestRes(@RequestBody HashMap<String, Object> dataHashMap) {
Object1 object1=  (Object1) JsonConvertor.jsonToObject((String) dataHashMap.get("object1"), Object1.class);
    Object2 object2= (Object2) JsonConvertor.jsonToObject((String) dataHashMap.get("object2"), Object2.class);   
}
```

Somthing like above should work. BUT if not you can have a wrapper object and pass that hashmap as key value string from client and then parse in in Java to a hashmap.

Comment: I guess this is the solution if nothing works. But i really wants to know the root cause. At least some change notes in the subsequent spring boot releases.